# Passing DB and Schema name as parameters in Snowflake using binds and receiving error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am passing the Database and schemaname as parameters in Snowflake stored procedure using Binds, not sure what the syntax error are that I see. Request your help.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB_SCHEMA VARCHAR) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        var sql_command = ` CREATE TABLE :1.TEST_KK AS SELECT * FROM :1.DIM_ACTIVITY_HIER`;
         snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DB_SCHEMA]});

    return 'success';
    $$;
call repo('DB_DEV.DMS')
```

I have tried using storing the DB and schema name in one variable and bind that variable as well, as shown below, and I get the error too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB_SCHEMA STRING) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        var DB_SC = DB_SCHEMA;
         
         var sql_command = ` CREATE TABLE ?.TEST_KK AS SELECT * FROM ?.DIM_ACTIVITY_HIER`;
         snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DB_SC]});

         
    return DB_SC;
    $$;
call repo('DB_DEV.DMS')
```

other way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB_SCHEMA STRING) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        var DB_SC = DB_SCHEMA;
         
         var sql_command = ` CREATE TABLE :1.TEST_KK AS SELECT * FROM :1.DIM_ACTIVITY_HIER`;
         snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DB_SC]});

         
    return DB_SC;
    $$;
call repo('DB_DEV.DMS')
```

I get the syntax error as below:

For 2nd code : execution error in stored procedure REPO:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 14 unexpected '?'.
> Syntax error line 1 at position 24 unexpected 'AS'.
> Syntax error line 1 at position 41 unexpected '?'.
> At Snowflake.execute, line 5 position 13

For 3rd code: Execution error in stored procedure REPO:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 14 unexpected ':'.
> Syntax error line 1 at position 25 unexpected 'AS'.
> Syntax error line 1 at position 42 unexpected ':'.
> At Snowflake.execute, line 5 position 13

Comment: Apologies, tried with binds: [DB_SCHEMA], code pasted has a typo but I still get the same errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use bind variables for partial object names. You can use them for the entire object name (three part or using context) using the IDENTIFIER() SQL function.

If you want to use partial names, the easiest way to do that is using template literals in JavaScript. This will only work when you use backticks to open and close your string, as you did in your example code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB_SCHEMA VARCHAR) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        var sql_command = ` CREATE TABLE ${DB_SCHEMA}.TEST_KK AS SELECT * FROM ${DB_SCHEMA}.DIM_ACTIVITY_HIER`;
         snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command});

    return 'success';
    $$;
call repo('DB_DEV.DMS')
```

Comment: Usage of templating like ` var sql_command = ` CREATE TABLE ${DB_SCHEMA}.TEST_KK AS`  could easily be overused e.g. `CALL repo('DB_DEV.DMS.TEST_KK AS SELECT * FROM any_other_table --')`.

Comment: It's something to be mindful of, but a SQL injection attack is relevant only when it allows the user to do something he or she wouldn't be able to do otherwise. One way to make that attack irrelevant is defining the SP using `execute as caller`. Another way is to grant usage to only the role owning the SP, which is common.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @Greg Pavlik. I tried the below and it works too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB_SCHEMA STRING) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        var DB_SC = DB_SCHEMA;
         
         var sql_command ="CREATE TABLE "+ DB_SC +".TEST_KK " + "AS SELECT * FROM " + DB_SC+ ".DIM_ACTIVITY_HIER";
         snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DB_SC]});

         
    return DB_SC;
    $$;
```